# Mutiply DataFrame columns with different weights

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, scalar, multiplication

I need to multiply individual columns in a dataframe by weights.
So I have the following code

```
df.C1 *= 0.2
df.C2 *= 0.01
```

Is there a better or short way of doing it, possibly a list of weights multiplied to columns?

Something like `df.cols.values *= list(weights)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
df1.loc[:,cols]=df1[cols].values*[100,10]
```

Comment: you mean df1.loc[:,cols]=df1[[cols]].values*[100,10]?

Comment: @Wajih cols is list of columns like cols=[col1,col2...colm]